# How to override a JavaScript function in twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We currently use Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 and I am trying to figure out a way to tie into the toggle function that is part of the dropdown component.  I am trying to do this globally and have come up with this code:

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined)
{
    var oldToggle = $.fn.dropdown.Constructor.prototype.toggle;

    $.fn.dropdown.Constructor.prototype.toggle = function (e)
        {
            console.log('here');
            return oldToggle.call(this, e);
        }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

When I put this code in the bootstrap file, the override works fine.  When I try to include it elsewhere on the page my console.log never executes.  What am I missing here?

Here is a link to a JSFiddle that includes the code posted above
http://jsfiddle.net/whoiskb/8nvuk/1/

Comment: you need to add it after the bootstrap.js file... also, does the  console show any errors?

Comment: When I include the script, it is included after the bootstrap file.  The console does not show any errors.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with how Bootstrap works, but is it possible that this is happening?: 1) Bootstrap code runs 2) "Toggle" event handlers are attached to elements on the page 3) Your code overrides Bootstrap function in dropdown prototype, but is now too late.

Comment: @Zhihao good guess. I was just posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to overwrite that function from outside. Look at the bootstrap source

```
$(document)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
```

as soon as this event is bound, any change to the prototype won't take effect, because the original function was passed and you can't take this back.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L141

Comment: That does make sense, I did over look that.  I now tried to see if I could rebind the event but that doesn't seem to be working.  Shouldn't I be able to remove the existing event with                 $(document).off('click.bs.dropdown.data-api')

Comment: It should be `$(document).off('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '[data-toggle=dropdown]')`, but for some reason that doesn't work in your fiddle.